# Backbone Marionette Region + Layout + View hierarchy and responsiveness

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js, marionette

I am writing my first `Marionette` app and would like to use the `Marionette` UI structure.

My understanding is that, roughly speaking,

- A `Region` is 1:1 with an *existing*, single DOM node (like a `div` or a `span`) and may contain `View`s, including the special ones provided by `Marionette`
- A `Layout` is a `View` as well as a container of `Region`s and specifies a `template` by which those regions will be arranged; as a `View` it may be rendered into a `Region`

So I think this means you must follow this sort of hierarchy:

```
- Root (region) [could be more than one]
-- Layout A
--- Inner Region A1
--- Inner Region A2
-- Layout B
--- Inner Region B1
--- Inner Region B2
-- View C
--- maybe some subviews?
```

If my assumptions are wrong, please correct.

In any case, my application has a navigation and content area in the UI. Now, when the script is loaded, we may be loading it into a page that already has `div#region-navigation` in place to customize the appearance, or we may be loading it into a page without the node in place. If the navigation node is in place, we don't need to render it, but we do need to be able to maintain a reference to it and do things to it ("Log In" => "Log Out" for instance). On the other hand, if it is not in place, we need to render and maintain it.

My question is: what is the "Marionette" way to handle this? I have thought of one way, but I would really like to avoid going down any unnecessarily painful paths.

My solution is to create an absolute `RootRegion` that is a single selector (default `body`) that definitely does not exist at the time of creation.

I would have two `AppLayout`s: an `InjectedAppLayout`, where the layout only has a `Content` region, and a `ManagedAppLayout`, where the layout replaces the contents of `body`.

Then based on the `script` tag `data-` params and/or what is on the page (using jQuery) I can choose which `Layout` to use.

In either case, I have a `HeaderRegion` and a `ContentRegion`. In the case of an `InjectedAppLayout` the `HeaderRegion` lives outside while the `ManagedAppLayout` contains both. Then, I would possibly need to make a separate `ExternalHeaderRegion` and `InternalHeaderRegion` or use a conditional because I would need to handle things very differently depending on whether it is being managed by me or not.

This seems very sub-optimal but I haven't found any example of how people manage this.

Finally, in the case of an `InjectedAppLayout`, I am afraid that the `div` containing the `ContentLayout` may be very small even if the screen width is big because I do not control it. My styles, using `Bootstrap` and media queries, all use `max-width` values to determine which styles to set. My question is: will the `@media (max-width: XXXpx)` queries still apply to the containing `div` in the case of the injected app layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used following structure

```
-Marionette Application (root - have regions hash of existing node elements)
-- LayoutView (breaks application region in sub regions if needed)

---CollectionView || CompositeView (render collections)
----ItemView
||
---LayoutView (create more sub-regions) 
---- (other sub views)
||
---ItemView (render model)
```

+Router and controllers for application statuses maintain

Lets separate responses between this stuff

**[Application](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md)** - starts first.
In charge of keeping constants and global params, start and stop sub modules load default routers and controllers + provide Request/Response channel.

1) Can receive some extra params on start

```
var options = {
  something: "some value",
  another: "#some-selector"
};

MyApp.start(options);
```

2) have regions has to work with existing nodes (navs, content, footer, sidebars and so on)

```
MyApp.addRegions({
  someRegion: "#some-div",
  anotherRegion: "#another-div"
});
```

So you can provide some params to JS to render correct views + you can hook-up your application with node elements

**[Router](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.approuter.md)** and **[Controller](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.controller.md)**

Helps you to render correct view according to application status.
In charge of keeping application view correct according to the url and provide navigation 
You can use it with links + navigate manually with **navigate** method

```
var MyRouter = new Marionette.AppRouter({
  controller: myController,
  appRoutes: {
    "foo": "doFoo",
    "bar/:id": "doBar"
  }
});
```

**[LayoutView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layoutview.md)**
In Charge of rendering and closing subviews. Separate parent node in some child

```
Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: "#layout-view-template",

  regions: {
    menu: "#menu",
    content: "#content"
  }
});
```

Using this structure you can pass to application some params to let application know if user loged in or not. According to this you can add regions with **addRegions** and render some Layouts (like 'UserNav' or 'GuestNav') . Layout will render its child views like UserLinks, UserAvatar and so on. Then user click links Router and Controller handle this and tell Application what to render in some region.

Comment: Thank you for the beautifully-detailed answer. One question: WHEN (in terms of events or the app-view lifecycle or both) is it appropriate to render the initial views inside each region or layout, and WHAT should be responsible for doing so (you mention in your answer that your layouts render their child views... is this the general pattern people follow?)

Comment: One more question: In general, regions selected by `id` and their direct children are kind of like singletons, so in many cases I want to get and maybe maintain a reference to a region or layout or view. What is the best way to do this? Or should I try to drive everything within the router-controller-events?

Comment: Answering your first question it depends on what initial view you have - if its just some static text or picture like ("waiting.. we are loading") you can put it in html, when some other view will render in this region it will override this text. If your initial view dynamic - you have to create route for initial state, render initialView and this initialView will be in charge to render ins content (fetch collection and render child list and so on). About layout usage i think yes, as the the main task of regionView render template and create sub regions.

Comment: For second question. Regions in Application is very close to singletons, as your Application should be singleton =) .The easiest way is to make application instance visible in global scope, like window.App = new Application, and you can access its region from any views. Second approach use marionette Module as independent part of UI, like header Modeule, footer Module. If i'm not mistaken each module have link to application in params.

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy. I should mention as for the second question I am using RequireJS

Comment: glad to help) with rJS, i guess, you load main.js, so in define method you pass array with application file module. make instance, make it global and start application instance. like this define(['jquery', 'app'], function($, App){
  $(function(){
   window.App = App;
   window.App.start();
  })
 }
);